# /dev/dsp missing in debian and cannot hear festival utterance

Tags: bash, audio, debian, speech, festival

Tried to make an utterance in festival and it seems /dev/dsp/ is missing in the debian. How to add this?

```
festival> (SayText "Hello")
Linux: can't open /dev/dsp
#<Utterance 0xb669c708>
```

Comment: Better suited for superuser.com. Or if it is ubuntu flavor, rather than pure debian, please ask on askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Followed the instruction on https://wiki.debian.org/SoundFAQ

installing oss-compat using

```
apt-get install oss-compat
```

solves the issue basically but might be good to load the snd-pcm-oss using

```
modprobe snd-pcm-oss
```

this has to be done as root. This will create the /dev/dsp and solve the issue.